# PHP mailer error : failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, sendmail, phpmailer

Hello there I receive following error while try to upload file using php mailer.

**move_uploaded_file(C:/inetpub/vhosts/yoursite.com/httpdocs/userfiles/resumes/5007story1.pdf) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\yoursite\wwwroot\jobseekers.php on line 87**

```
            global $imagesname;
        global $image_type;   
        $uid = rand(100,9999);
        if(isset($_FILES["img"]["name"]))
        {
            $image_tempname= $_FILES['img']['name'];

            $imgdir ="C:/inetpub/vhosts/yoursite.com/httpdocs/";// $_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
            //imgdir =$_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
            $imgname = $imgdir. 'userfiles/resumes/'.$uid.$_FILES['img']['name'];

            if($imagesname != '')
            {
                $imagesname=$imagesname.','.$imgname;
                $image_type=$image_type.','.$_FILES['img']['type'];
            }
            else
            {
                $imagesname=$imagesname.$imgname;
                $image_type=$image_type.$_FILES['img']['type'];
            }
            $imgurl = 'userfiles/resumes/'.$image_tempname;     
            //print_r($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']);

            move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $imgname); 

        }
        if(isset($_FILES["img"]['name']))
        {
            $filename=$uid.$_FILES["img"]["name"];
        }
        $fileField=$filename;
```

Line Number 87 Is:
**move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $imgname);**

Comment: Are you sure the directory you are trying to save the file to exists? IE, is the file path completely correct?

Comment: var_dump($imgname) and check if the img path actually exists.

Comment: @PhilCross , yes, I change on domain name to yoursite and yoursite.com for some security issues.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507